# Represent integers on d digits using smallest possible base

Tags: algorithm, sorting, radix

I'd like to create a function where for an arbitrary integer input value (let's say unsigned 32 bit) and a given number of `d` digits the return value will be a `d` digit `B` base number, `B` being the smallest base that can be used to represent the given input on `d` digits.

Here is a sample input - output of what I have in mind for 3 digits:

```
Input   Output

    0       0 0 0
    1       0 0 1
    2       0 1 0
    3       0 1 1
    4       1 0 0
    5       1 0 1
    6       1 1 0
    7       1 1 1

    8       0 0 2
    9       0 1 2
    10      1 0 2
    11      1 1 2
    12      0 2 0
    13      0 2 1
    14      1 2 0
    15      1 2 1
    16      2 0 0
    17      2 0 1
    18      2 1 0
    19      2 1 1
    20      0 2 2
    21      1 2 2
    22      2 0 2
    23      2 1 2
    24      2 2 0
    25      2 2 1
    26      2 2 2

    27      0 0 3
    28      0 1 3
    29      1 0 3
    30      1 1 3
    ..      .....
```

The assignment should be 1:1, for each input value there should be exactly one, unique output value. Think of it as if the function should return the `nth` value from the list of strangely sorted `B` base numbers.

Actually this is the only approach I could come up so far with - given an input value, generate all the numbers in the smallest possible `B` base to represent the input on `d` digits, then apply a custom sorting to the results ('penalizing' the higher digit values and putting them further back in the sort), and return the `nth` value from the sorted array. This would work, but is a spectacularly inefficient implementation - I'd like to do this without generating all the numbers up to the input value.

What would be an efficient approach for implementing this function? Any language or pseudocode is fine.

Comment: I don't understand the output for the numbers >= 8, can you explain?

Comment: @Henry Base 2 goes to `2^3-1`, base 3 goes to `3^3-1`, base 4 goes to `4^3-1`, etc.

Comment: Decimal 8 can not be represented on 3 digits in binary, so 8 should correspond to the first ternary number that is not a valid binary

Comment: What about checking the max number that is possible in base B of d digits. You can apply Binary search over base B. what is the expected time complexity?

Comment: @coderredoc I was hoping that there may be a solution that does not involve search or sort, but only a clever assignment. If that's not the case O(n) would be nice.

Comment: That would be more logical to use the standard base 3 (or n) in which case the outputs are 000 001 002 010 011 012 100 101 102 110 111 112 etc

Comment: Yes, the sorting is weird. Why is 10 "102" and not "020"? What s your sorting criterion? I thought it should be max. digit first, normal digit comparison next.

Comment: Can't you simply always use the highest possible base? What's the benefit of representing the smaller numbers in lower base?

Comment: Please fix the numbers greater than 7 (decimal)! 002 is never 8, regardless of the base. If your base is 3, 022 would equal eight. And so on...

Comment: This is a specific assigment of decimal values to d digit B base values. Nobody said that 8 decimal = 002 ternary. There is nothing to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MBo's answer shows how to find the smallest base that will represent an integer number with a given number of digits.

I'm not quite sure about the ordering in your example. My answer is based on a different ordering: Create all possible *n*-digit numbers up to base *b* (e.g. all numbers up to 999 for max. base 10 and 3 digits). Sort them according to their maximum digit first. Numbers are sorted normalls within a group with the same maximum digit. This retains the characteristic that all values from 8 to 26 must be base 3, but the internal ordering is different:

```
  8      0 0 2
  9      0 1 2
 10      0 2 0
 11      0 2 1
 12      0 2 2
 13      1 0 2
 14      1 1 2
 15      1 2 0
 16      1 2 1
 17      1 2 2
 18      2 0 0
 19      2 0 1
 20      2 0 2
 21      2 1 0
 22      2 1 1
 23      2 1 2
 24      2 2 0
 25      2 2 1
 26      2 2 2
```

When your base is two, life is easy: Just generate the appropriate binary number.

For other bases, let's look at the first digit. In the example above, five numbers start with 0, five start with 1 and nine start with 2. When the first digit is 2, the maximum digit is assured to be 2. Therefore, we can combine 2 with a 9 2-digit numbers of base 3.

When the first digit is smaller than the maximum digit in the group, we can combine it with the 9 2-digit numbers of base 3, but we must not use the 4 2-digit numbers that are ambiguous with the 4 2-digit numbers of base 2. That gives us five possibilites for the digits 0 and 1. These possibilities – 02, 12, 20, 21 and 22 –  can be described as the unique numbers with two digits according to the same scheme, but with an offset:

```
 4     0 2
 5     1 2
 6     2 0
 7     2 1
 8     2 2
```

That leads to a recursive solution:

- for one digit, just return the number itself;
- for base two, return the straightforward representation in base 2;
- if the first number is the maximum digit for the determined base, combine it with a straighforward representations in that base;
- otherwise combine it with a recursively determined representation of the same algorithm with one fewer digit.

Here's an example in Python. The representation is returned as list of numbers, so that you can represent 2^32 − 1 as [307, 1290, 990].

```
import math

def repres(x, ndigit, base):
    """Straightforward representation of x in given base"""

    s = []

    while ndigit:
        s += [x % base]
        x /= base
        ndigit -= 1

    return s



def encode(x, ndigit):
    """Encode according to min-base, fixed-digit order"""

    if ndigit <= 1:
        return [x]

    base = int(x ** (1.0 / ndigit)) + 1

    if base <= 2:
        return repres(x, ndigit, 2)

    x0 = (base - 1) ** ndigit
    nprev = (base - 1) ** (ndigit - 1)
    ncurr = base ** (ndigit - 1)
    ndiff = ncurr - nprev

    area = (x - x0) / ndiff

    if area < base - 1:
        xx = x0 / (base - 1) + x - x0 - area * ndiff
        return [area] + encode(xx, ndigit - 1)

    xx0 = x0 + (base - 1) * ndiff
    return [base - 1] + repres(x - xx0, ndigit - 1, base)



for x in range(32):
    r = encode(x, 3)
    print x, r
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after, I'll need to test this out and get back to you. The order in my example was arbitrary, the only important constraint for me is that binary numbers should precede ternaries that should precede quaternaties etc. Your solution seems to be a perfect fit for this.

Comment: Awesome! Works just as expected! ++ Many thanks, very clever and efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all values are positive, let's make simple math:
d-digit B-based number can hold value N if

B<sup>d</sup> > N

so

B > N<sup>1/d</sup>

So calculate N<sup>1/d</sup> value, round it up (increment if integer), and you will get the smallest base B.
*(note that numerical errors might occur)*

Examples:

```
d=2, N=99 => 9.95 => B=10
d=2, N=100 => 10  => B=11
d=2, N=57 => 7.55 => B=8
d=2, N=33 => 5.74 => B=6
```

Delphi code

```
  function GetInSmallestBase(N, d: UInt32): string;
  const
    Digits = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  var
    Base, i: Byte;
  begin
    Base := Ceil(Power(N, 1/d) + 1.0E-12);
    if Base > 36 then
      Exit('Big number, few digits...');
    SetLength(Result, d);
    for i := d downto 1 do begin
      Result[i] := Digits[1 + N mod Base]; //Delphi string is 1-based
      N := N div Base;
    end;
    Result := Result + Format(' : base [%d]', [Base]);
  end;

begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(GetInSmallestBase(99, 2));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(GetInSmallestBase(100, 2));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(GetInSmallestBase(987, 2));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(GetInSmallestBase(1987, 2));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(GetInSmallestBase(87654321, 6));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(GetInSmallestBase(57, 2));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(GetInSmallestBase(33, 2));

99 : base [10]
91 : base [11]
UR : base [32]
Big number, few digits...
H03LL7 : base [22]
71 : base [8]
53 : base [6]
```

Comment: That gives me the smallest B base the given input value can be represented in using d digits, but does not give me a unique B base number that corresponds to the input value. The final output, using your examples, should be 2-digit, Base 10, 11, 8 and 6 numbers, like "99", "0A", etc.

Comment: Digits may be calculated through integer division by base (and converting to proper symbols)